# Is there a way to get all permutations with the condition of unique adjacent elements?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I have the following Data, each letter of the Alphabet:

```
Letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
           'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

My goal is to get the maximum number of permutations of a length of 5, with the following 3 conditions:

1. No letter shall be repeated more than once in each permutation.
2. No permutation shall share more than 3 letters in common with another permutation in any position.
3. No permutation shall share more than 2 adjacent letters in common in an identical position with another permutation.

> e.g. Permutations `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']` and `['A', 'B', 'F', 'G', 'H']` should not be permitted as the same 'A' and 'B' are adjacent in both permutations. However, permutations `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']` and `['A', 'F', 'B', 'G', 'H']` should be permitted.

> Each permutation has 5 elements, `[Element 1, Element 2, Element 3, Element 4, Element 5]`. The neighbours of Element 1 is only Element 2. The neighbours of Element 2 is Element 1 and Element 3. For each permutation the neighbouring pairs are: `[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]`. No permutation should have the same neighbouring pair as another IF and only if they are in the same element position.

> Another similar example: `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']` and `['A', 'B', 'F', 'G', 'H']`. In the neighbouring pair of both permutations, `[Element 1, Element 2]` is  `['A', 'B']`. As they are identical at the same Element location, the solution is not valid.

> If however: `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']` and `['F', 'A', 'B', 'G', 'H']`. In this example, although they both have a neighbouring pair `['A', 'B']`, they are found in different Element locations `[Element 1, Element 2]` and `[Element 2, Element 3]` respectively. Therefore, they are both valid for the solution.

I have tried two different approaches to solve this task - using `itertools` with if conditions and mixed integer programming.

In terms of using `itertools`, I was not able to successfully define the conditions. I tried the following style of approach, with no luck:

```
from itertools import permutations
AllPermutations = list(permutations(Letters, 5))
ActualPermutations = []
for Permutation in AllPermutations:
    if Permutation[0:2] not in [Permutation[0:2] for Permutation in ActualPermutations]:
        ActualPermutations.append(Permutation)
```

While with mixed integer programming, I was not able to wrap my head around the objective function, as I was not minimizing or maximizing anything. Furthermore, mixed integer programming would only give me 1 permutation that fits with the constraints.

Comment: Are you only interested in the number of such elements (combinatorics) or also the actual elements?

Comment: @AlexG The actual elements as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please check if that solution matches your expectations? If so, I can provide some explanation.

```
from itertools import combinations


def three_letters_sub_set(letters):
    return combinations(letters, 3)

def adjacent_letters_sub_set(letters):
    for position in range(len(letters) - 1):
        adjacent_letters = (letters[position], letters[position + 1])
        yield position, adjacent_letters

def fails_rule2(letters):
    return any(
        three_letters in existing_three_letter_tuples
        for three_letters in three_letters_sub_set(letters)
    )

def fails_rule3(letters):
    for position, adjacent_letters in adjacent_letters_sub_set(letters):
        if adjacent_letters in existing_adjacent_letters[position]:
            return True
    return False

n_letters = 5
existing_three_letter_tuples = set()
existing_adjacent_letters = {position: set() for position in range(n_letters - 1)}

for comb in combinations(Letters, n_letters):
    if fails_rule2(comb):
        continue
    if fails_rule3(comb):
        continue

    existing_three_letter_tuples.update(three_letters_sub_set(comb))
    for position, adjacent_letters in adjacent_letters_sub_set(comb):
        existing_adjacent_letters[position].add(adjacent_letters)

    print(comb)
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt @AlexG ! Unfortunately the first 2 combinations, ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') and ('A', 'B', 'F', 'G', 'H') both contain the neighbouring pair 'A', 'B' is the same position, therefore breaking rule 3. 

Also, I could be wrong, but permutations might be the way to go. I fully understand that combinations are normally used to satisfy condition 1. No letter shall be repeated more than once in each permutation. However, with the 2nd and 3rd conditions filtering out many combinations later on, some possibilities remain that could possibly be a solution.

Comment: I fixed the issue with the neighbouring pair. Please check again.

Can you explain why you would go with permutations instead of combinations? Using combinations satisfies exactly your rule1: No letter shall be repeated more than once in each permutation. The only difference is, that combinations are sorted, so you would never get [DACBE] but [ABCDE] instead. Do you think this has an influence on the solution? So do you care if you get one instead of the other (obviously you can't have both)?

Comment: Thank you so much @AlexG, your solution works perfectly! I just tested it with your exact code, replacing combination with permutations and every result fits all 3 rules. I have therefore accepted your answer!